# Angular 5 Rxjs map return if condation

Tags: angular, maps, rxjs

hi im trying but i can not, so i want get country name with function in google maps api

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

findMapData(results): string {
    return results.results[0].address_components.map(res => {
        return res.types[0] === 'country' ? res.short_name : "";
    });
}

this.findMapData(mapData);
```

I need just country name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find instead

```
findMapData(results): string {
    return results.results[0].address_components.find(res => res.types[0] === country).short_name;
}
```

then

```
this.findMapData(mapData);
```

Comment: not working ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: you need types instead of type